# Redireccionamiento a página de error 404 en .net core 3.0

Tags: .net-core, error404

Necesito saber cómo puedo redireccionar a una página de error 404 Not Found en .net core, para que cuando un usuario acceda a un recurso inexistente o eliminado, automáticamente se redirija a esta página de error, tengo una página personalizada con el error pero quiero saber cuál es el proceso para redireccionarla

Comment: Te recomendaría revisar [ask] y [repro]. Es importante que tu pregunta venga acompañada de algo del código que tengas, sobre todo para tener algo más de contexto.

Comment: Lo tomaré en cuenta, gracias

Comment: @CliverMiranda: Recuerda siempre valorar las respuestas que te han ayudado a solucionar tu pregunta, y marcar el check verde al lado de la respuesta que te ha solucionado la pregunta, 
con eso estarás colaborando con la buena salud de este sitio. Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En el archivo **Startup.cs**, debes de declarar en el **pipeline** de la aplicación (`public void Configure(..)`) el **middleware** `UseStatusCodePages()` con la dirección de la página a redirigir:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseStatusCodePages(async context =>
        {
            if (context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode == 404)
            {
                context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("~/Views/Shared/Errors/_NotFound.cshtml");
            }
        });

        // ...

     }
```

Comment: ¿Esta respuesta solucionó tu problema, @cliver?,  Por favor no olvides marcarla como aceptada si tu problema fue resuelto. Puedes hacerlo marcando el ✓ en la parte izquierda de la respuesta (se pondrá verde, ganarás 2 puntos de reputación y podrías acceder a nuevos privilegios). Mira [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) si tienes alguna duda!